# Rails set values on form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to auto fill a field when a drop down item is selected OR find and set the attributes when the create method is called. Specifically the mid (MachineID) located in a different class (Part). Partconfig belongs_to Part. Part has many Partconfig.

PartConfig

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.select :Part_id, Part.all.collect{ |c| [c.name, c.id] } %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :mid %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :mid %>
  </div>
```

I thought I could do this in the create controller method:

```
 @part_config = PartConfig.new(params[:part_config])
 @part_config.mid = Part.find_by_name(params[:name]).select("mid")
```

Which does not work.

Comment: It looks like you're using form_for. What is the form **for**? This will change the params passed. For example, if you have form_for(@object), the param name will be presented as {:object => {:name => 'this is a name'}}. That might be why params[:name] is picking up nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the line

```
@part_config.mid = Part.find_by_name(params[:name]).select("mid")
```

I was trying to let the user select the mid from a drop down list, which wasn't necessary. Picking the name yields part_id witch the association allows me to call

```
@part_config = PartConfig.includes(:part).find(params[:id])
```

This returns the PART_CONFIG and the associated PART allowing me to do this in the view:

```
@part_config.part.mid
```

Resulting in exactly what I wanted!